# Pop-up (error message) window doesn’t come to front

Tags: bug, comments, design

I recently tried to add two comments in rapid succession on SU and I got this error message pop-up window:

[image: Screen snapshot showing error message pop-up window obscured by the “Chatting” screen element]

As you can see, it’s unreadable, because the “Chatting” screen element is in front of it.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Internet Explorer 8.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to happen when IE8 is running in compatibility mode, at least that's how I managed to reproduce the issue.

Solution: check to see if compatibility mode is active, and if it is, disable it. There's two ways to do that:

- if you see the compatibility mode icon next to the address bar, click on it:

  [image]
- alternatively, hit <kbd>F12</kbd> to open Developer Tools, then select Browser Mode → Internet Explorer 8

  [image]